# No module found at django deployment (apache,wsgi)

Tags: python, django, apache, import, apache2

I have deployed a small django application, and I want to display a graph on a page. For the realization of graphs in python I use the plotly library. In production, the import of plotly worked very well, no worries. But when deploying django with apache2 and wsgi, there is an import problem that the plotly module is not found, I don't know how to do that for several hours now. If some have already encountered this kind of problems....

thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

do you use virtualenviroument?
it is better to make a requiments.txt file in project and install in your virtual enviroument you can use freeze in pip and install when you active virtualenv with

```
source virtualenv/bin/activate
```